# How can I add a column with find the closest date found in a second table using dax or m?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have two tables. One with dates of tech support given, and the other one with surveys sent to the customers. The problem is that the surveys are sent some days after the service is done. So I need to find the closest date from the survey table and bring it to my tech support table. Here's a sample of my data and the result wanted. I appreciate any help!

```
Table1: 
TechSupportDate
01/12/2018
02/12/2018
05/12/2018

Table2:
SurveyDate
04/12/2018
10/12/2018
12/12/2018
```

**Expected Result:**

```
TechSupportDate     SurveyDate
01/12/2018          04/12/2018
02/12/2018          04/12/2018
05/12/2018          10/12/2018
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a calculated column to Table1:

```
SurveyDate = 
CALCULATE ( 
    MIN ( Table2[SurveyDate] ),
    FILTER ( 
        Table2,
        Table2[SurveyDate] >= Table1[TechSupportDate]
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank's! Worked perfectly!

Comment: I posted a new question related to this one. I would appreciate it if you could take a look! @Olly
https://stackoverflow.com/q/54693431/11058931